# Can't create a draggable pin on Bing maps

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I can't figure out how to make a draggable pushpin. I used this code that is similar to tutorial I can find everywhere:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetMap()
    {
        var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.1, 2.20696);

        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            , center: loc,
            zoom:16

        });

        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
        pin.setOptions( { draggable: true, text:'1' });
        map.entities.push(pin);
    }
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
<div id="myMap" class="bing"></div>
```

But it is not working.

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushpins were not draggable in the initial release of V8, however this functionality has been added in the experimental branch of V8. Simply add "&branch=experimental" to the map script URL and your pushpin will be draggable. All new features and bug fixes that are currently in the experimental branch will be rolled into the main release branch at the end of the month.